# How do I update this regex to only match 9 digits (and no more)?

Tags: regex

I'm using a proprietary software to look in the body of an email for an SSN using this regex: `((?!666|000)[0-8][0-9\_]{2}[.-]?(?!00)[0-9\_]{2}[.-]?(?!0000)[0-9\_]{4})`

It's a pretty common SSN regex and works great.

My issue is that this will only match the SSN when it is the ONLY thing in the body. So to get around that, I'm adding .* and .* to the beginning and end. Which works great.

Now my issue is that it is also matching numbers with 10 digits, which is a different number - our account number. Finally the question - anyway to take this regex and only look for 9 digits. I'm thinking \d{9} but not sure how to append it on to the end.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `.*\b((?:(?!666|000)[0-8][0-9_]{2}[.-]?(?!00)[0-9_]{2}[.-]?(?!0000)[0-9_]{4}|[0-9]{9}))\b.*`  https://regex101.com/r/kfceye/1

Comment: No. That regex will match the SSN **anywhere** in a string, since it has no `^` `$` anchors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a proprietary software where you have to use `.*` to get a full match you could make use of word boundaries `\b` and an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match your pattern or 9 digits.

Note that you don't have to escape the underscore in the character class.

```
.*\b((?:(?!666|000)[0-8][0-9_]{2}[.-]?(?!00)[0-9_]{2}[.-]?(?!0000)[0-9_]{4}|[0-9]{9}))\b.*
                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kfceye/1/)

---

If [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are supported, you might also assert what is on the left and on the right is not a non whitespace char using `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)`

```
.*(?<!\S)((?:(?!666|000)[0-8][0-9_]{2}[.-]?(?!00)[0-9_]{2}[.-]?(?!0000)[0-9_]{4}|[0-9]{9}))(?!\S).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7i5HsI/1)

Answer (score 0):

While this may not look very fun at all, it will validate any valid Social Security Number as per the constraints (and exceptions) listed by the Social Security Administration.

^(?!219099999|078051120)(?!666|000|9\d{2})\d{3}(?!00)\d{2}(?!0{4})\d{4}$

Sorry for bad paste here.

^                           # Start of expression
(?!219-09-9999|078-05-1120) # Don't allow "219-09-999" or "078-05-1120" explicitly
(?!666|000|9\d{2})\d{3}     # Don't allow the SSN to begin with 666, 000 or anything between 900-999
-                           # Explicit dash (separating Area and Group numbers)
(?!00)\d{2}                 # Don't allow the Group Number to be "00"
-                           # Another dash (separating Group and Serial numbers)
(?!0{4})\d{4}               # Don't allow last four digits to be "0000"
$                           # End of expression

Follow instructions found here http://rion.io/2013/09/10/validating-social-security-numbers-through-regular-expressions-2/

Hope this helps!